convolution-like computation of bivariate distribution
I would like to optimize code to compute a bivariate distribution like this (for example the bivariate poisson distribution):
$f_{n,m} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i \times b_{n-i} \times c_{m-i}$
It really looks like a convolution, and in the real domain we can quite easily prove, applying fourier transform that, for a given $f(x, y) = \int_t a(t) \times b(x-t) \times c(y-t) dt$,
$F(x, y) = A(x+y) \times B(x) \times C(y)$ where $F$, $A$, $B$ and $C$ are fourier transforms of respectively $f$, $a$, $b$ and $c$
Is it possible to make the same kind of thing in the discrete domain, so that we can use fft to compute this kind of "semi" convolution ?
NB : I tried the "naive" idea to assume that it was also true for discrete series and wrote in python the following code:
def joint_bivariate_poisson_fft(lambd1, lambd2, lambd3, size):
    n, m = np.indices((2*size, 2*size))
    sum_indices = n + m
    p_1 = np.pad(poisson_pmf_1D(lambd1, size), (size, 0))
    p_2 = np.pad(poisson_pmf_1D(lambd2, size), (size, 0))
    p_3 = np.pad(poisson_pmf_1D(lambd3, 2*size), (2*size, 0))
    return np.fft.ifft2(
        np.fft.fft(p_1).reshape(2*size, 1) * 
        np.fft.fft(p_2).reshape(1, 2*size) *
        np.fft.fft(p_3)[sum_indices]
    ).real

But it doesn't make the right distribution for the example of bivariate poisson distribution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform
